# Refreshing a div on 2 pages at once with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

Let me explain.

I have a page that lists a bunch of posts.

Each post shows a clickable reply icon that opens a fancybox overlay containing the single post. The icon also shows the reply count next to it. This icon appears on both the main page and in the pop up window (although on the pop up it is deactivated, it's just there to show the post count).

I'm using AJAX to post and delete replies. The php functions are all in place and working.

So when I delete a post in the fancybox pop up the following updates the reply count :

```
 $(".reply-count").load(location.href + " .reply-count");
```

This is the full function for clarity :

```
 $(document).on( 'click', '.comment-delete', function() {
    var r = confirm("Delete This Comment?");
    if (r == true) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var nonce = $(this).data('nonce');
    var post = $(this).parents('.post:first');
    var space = (" ");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'my_delete_comment',
            nonce: nonce,
            id: id
        },
        success: function( result ) {
            if( result == 'success' ) {
                $('#div-comment-' + id).fadeOut('slow');
                $(".reply-count").load(location.href + " .reply-count");
            }
        }
    })
    }
    return false;
})
```

This works just great, but it's only reloading the .reply-count div in the fancybox pop up window, and not on the main page.

Is there a way for jQuery to update the same .reply-count div on the main page as well, or can jQuery only work within the current window?

Alternatively, maybe I can add a call to reload the div on the main page when the fancybox pop up is closed?

Comment: Fancybox opens a modal window, so technically it is the same browser window. I see no reason for that not to work. However, some html code would be of help if you want a specific jquery line of code.

Comment: Why are you using a div element for load();? it only accepts HTML, JSON and some AJAX files

Comment: @Ivan well it's working?

Comment: In that case you use location.href + " .reply-count" it would render www.domain.com/page.reply-count

Comment: Ok so I need to target the div that wraps the post on the main page as well then right?

Comment: Perhaps you could try "<div> ... </div>" inside of  load where it can get URL parameter into a specific element. I cannot help you without JSfiddle, you would add simple implementation and let's solve.

Comment: Ok I will try that. It's a very complicated set up that is being generated largely by PHP / MySQL, would take me hours to convert it into a fiddle so i'll just keep trying things. Thanks for your help though!